In Azure Devops Yaml pipeline determine if branch being built is the main branch
The company that I'm at, uses Azure Devops to build and deploy applications. We have many products that need to be built and deployed, this is currently done using classic (build) pipelines and releases. We have started moving to Yaml pipelines and I'm creating a git repository 'SharedTemplates' that will hold Yaml templates that will be used by several pipelines. As an illustration, git repo 'RepoXX' has a pipeline 'XX', git repo 'RepoYY' has pipeline 'YY' and git repo 'RepoZZ' has pipeline 'ZZ', and all these pipelines will make use of the templates in git repo 'SharedTemplates'.
Note that 'SharedTemplates' does not contain any pipeline itself, it only contains reusable templates that are to be consumed by pipelines 'XX' etc.
In 'SharedTemplates' I want to create a template 'DoFancyStuff' that should perform either action A or B depending on whether the branch being built is the repository's main branch. This condition is proving to be a bit challenging. Sure, there is the predefined variable Build.SourceBranchName, but in git repo 'RepoXX', the main branch is called 'dev', in git repo 'RepoYY', the main branch is called 'master' and in 'RepoZZ' the main branch is called 'main'. Thus, when template 'DoFancyStuff' is run as part of pipeline 'XX', it should perform action A if Build.SourceBranchName is dev and otherwise action B. When pipeline 'YY' is executing, 'DoFancyStuff' should perform action A if Build.SourceBranchName is master, etc.
To determine in template 'DoFancyStuff' whether to perform action A or B I can add another parameter mainBranchName to template 'DoFancyStuff' and subsequently compare Build.SourceBranchName to mainBranchName. However, that means that I have to add that parameter mainBranchName to all my pipelines, which I'd like to avoid if possible. Therefore, I'd like to know if there is some way that I in template 'DoFancyStuff' can determine what the main branch name is for the pipeline that invoked DoFancyStuff. The only documentation that I've found so far is the documentation of the pipeline default branch but I cannot figure out how use this information in the 'DoFancyStuff' template.
Any suggestions?

Hi Simon, So you would expect to know the default branch of the repo that is trying to consuming the template is main or master then decide with actions to be taken? I don't see if that is necessary. Would you consider the expression like ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main' ), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master' )) }}:? Thus, either the pipelines was triggered by main or master branch could execute the same set of actions(stages/jobs/steps).

To help understand your scenario as you mentioned, Yaml templates that will be used by several pipelines, so these pipelines are referencing the their .yml definition files in different branches dev master or main in different repos?

In addition, a single pipeline can be triggered by the xxx.yml file with the same name but different contents from different branches (dev or main) of the same repo. Then the value of variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] can be dev or main according to the triggering branch.

By some of our git repositories the main branch is called 'dev', other repositories have 'master' as main branch, and the newest flavor is 'main'. do you mean the default branches of your repos are dev master or main? Based on the information above, your pipelines don't only get triggered by the repos default branch do they? The pipeline default branch is selected especially when your pipeline is triggered manually or by schedule; it isn't always your repo default branch. Can you please specify your scenario with your actual expectations in this post? Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I've updated the question to hopefully better explain my situation and what I'm trying to achieve.

Hi Simon, Thanks for your update. But I am afraid there is setting like in git repo 'RepoXX', the main branch is called 'dev'; main branch is main branch and dev branch is dev branch. If you mean RepoXX default branch is dev, RepoYY default branch is master and RepoZZ default branch 'main', you should be able to see the default tag on those branches in each repo.

So the actual requirement is not to define defaulBranch name in each pipeline but only determin and evaluate the defaulBranch in template. I think you can define defaulBranch in the template based on the Build.Repository.Name or even System.DefinitionId.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT You're correct, it should be: RepoXX default branch is dev etc. Maybe a tag will work, I'll dive into that later.

Hi Simon, I have tested to dynamically set the variable value in template based on the variables['Build.Repository.Name']. You may adjust the expressions based on your actual YAML pipeline structure. Hope it may help resolve your query in this post. Appreciate your time and efforts.

Update
In your template DoFancyStuff NOT in your pipeline YAML definitions, add the Azure DevOps CLI - az repos show in a script as shown below. This script outputs the variable $defaultBranch of each $(Build.Repository.Name) of the corresponding pipeline that expands this template, for evaluating  condition in downstream stage/job/step at pipeline runtime.
Since you didn't share any specific YAML context, we were unable to know whether stages, jobs or steps were defined in your template DoFancyStuff. The sample template just uses a step to represent Action A or B. Adjust it according to your template's structure.
DoFancyStuff.yml
- pwsh: |
    $response = az repos show --repository "$(Build.Repository.Name)" `
      --org "$(System.CollectionUri)" `
      --project "$(System.TeamProject)"
    $json = $response | ConvertFrom-Json
    $defaultBranch = $json.defaultBranch
    Write-Host "Default Branch of $(Build.Repository.Name): $defaultBranch"
    Write-Host "Build.SourceBranch: $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=defaultBranch;]$defaultBranch"
  displayName: Check default branch
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "Perform Action A"
  displayName: Perform Action A
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['defaultBranch'])
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "Perform Action B"
  displayName: Perform Action B
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['defaultBranch'])


To evaluate output variables in future jobs/stages, see Levels of output variables.

Based on the further discussions, the requirement is not to set defaultBranchName in each pipeline to be passed into the shared template for evaluation, but to determine the default branch inside the shared template to perform different actions when the triggering branch of the pipelines is the default branch of the repo.
Here is a sample template for your reference. You may try to extend or insert the template based on your YAML pipeline structure.
DoFancyStuff.yml
variables:
- name: defaultBranchName
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'RepoXX') }}:
    value: dev
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'RepoYY') }}:
    value: master
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'RepoZZ') }}:
    value: main

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['defaultBranchName'] ) }}:
  - script: |
      echo "Perform action A"
    displayName: Perform action A
- ${{ else }}:
  - script: |
      echo "Perform action B"
    displayName: Perform action B




Thanks for the suggestion, but this will not really help. The provided answer suggests that the DoFancyStuff, which contains shared templates, will have to know what the default branch is for several git repositories. In my example I only mentioned XX, YY and ZZ, but we have many more repositories.

So far I think that passing down the repository's main branch name is the only solution, but the situation is a bit more complicated than sketched above: Pipeline XX will use  templateA from git repo 'SharedTemplates', templateA will use templateB, which will use templateC. Template C contains the condition mentioned in the question. So, not only will I have to update all pipelines, but also templateA and templateB.

So, another requirement is not to hardcode each repo in the template?

I don't quite understand your pipeline structure. I just used a simple step to represent Action A.

You said your pipelineXX YY ZZ would use the same template 'DoFancyStuff', I shared the template file DoFancyStuff.yml as stated in the answer, which was not your pipeline YAML definition.

I wonder if I have any misunderstanding of your expectations or you have any misunderstanding of my answer?

It's indeed not trivial to describe the workflow ;) In short. pipeline XX (repoXX) calls tempateA (SharedTemplates repo), which calls templateB (also SharedTemplates repo), which calls template DoFancyStuff (in SharedTemplates repo).  The same flow applies for pipelines YY, ZZ, AA, BB, which are all in separate git repos.

@SimonAx, There is no function out-of-the-box or predefine variable to evaluate if the triggering branch is the repo default branch. Try and use a script to output the repo default branch as in my updated answer.
